# generate html overview from db table & column comments & metadata

Tags: sql, html, database, documentation

Is there an opensource tool which generates html overview for db tables based on table & columnt comments & all other db metadata (types of columns). I'm working with a new db which is well documented in comments and like to have a html/pdf overview of the entire db (meta level).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [SchemaCrawler](http://www.schemacrawler.com/), an open-source and free tool that generates database metadata documentation, including column comments, column data-types and so on, in HTML format. You can even generate database diagrams.

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler